# how to appengine with multithread on localhost

Tags: python, multithreading, google-app-engine

i am using python2.7, google app engine on my local server and mysql database(appengine rdbms)

my application run perfectyl (one connection) but when two or more connection same time,
i get *1054 socket error* because basehttpserver don't support multithreading
can i find any way fix this situation

can i my appengine application deploy to apache or how to multithread build on localhost

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 284, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 310, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2734, in __init__
    BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 639, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\BaseHTTPServer.py", line 343, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\BaseHTTPServer.py", line 313, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 476, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
error: [Errno 10054]
```

Comment: Do you have
threadsafe: true
In your app.yaml?

Comment: hi Paul C, yes my threadsafe is true

Answer (score 0):

```
from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn # socketserver in Python 3
class ThreadingHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn, BaseHTTPServer): pass # see line 628 in SocketServer.py
```

You want a multithreading `BaseHTTPServer`. `BaseHTTPServer` inherits from `TCPServer` which is singlethreaded. `SocketServer` defines `ThreadingTCPServer` using the `ThreadingMixIn`.
This mixin can be mixed into the `BaseHTTPServer` like above.

Note on the error:
The error means that the connection was reset before the http-request's first line (GET ...). This is not a problem for the BaseHTTPServer. It should run on.

Tell me if it does not resolve the Problem.